# Regex remove json property

Tags: javascript, json, regex, dust.js

I'd like to remove a stringfied json's property based on its key wherever it is, whatever its value type is. But removing it only if its value is a string and its on the root level of the object would be nice for a beggining. I tried this:

```
[,]{1}[\s]*?\"attrName\"[ ]*?[:][ ]*?\".*\"[^,]|\"attrName\"[ ]*?[:][ ]*?\".*\"[,]{0,1}
```

Example : https://regex101.com/r/PAlqYi/1

but it looks a lot big to do such a simple job, what it does is ensure the comma will be removed as well, if attrName is the first attribute, the last ot something in the middle of the json three. Does anyone has a better idea to make this regex more readable?

Comment: **Why** are you trying to use regex to modify JSON from a JS environment?

Comment: A regexp can’t do that. You’ll have to parse the JSON.

Comment: `var obj = JSON.parse(str); delete obj[attrName]; str = JSON.stringify(obj);`

Comment: decode the JSON object then unset the value that you're looking for and encode it again. no regex is required.

Comment: RegEx can do this, and surely someone will give you the regex (I won't). **Don't**. There is literally no reason to do this. Regex does not parse strings, merely follows a pattern. Regex can be fooled and while this particular solution could be locktight, it's a terrible and truly senseless habit to get into. **I encourage other users to avoid the internet-points and let this user perform the task properly.**

Comment: Also, why are you doing things like `[,]{1}` in your regex?  Just use `,`!

Comment: I cannot use plain JS, it's not a javascript environment but a system which uses dust js template engine, where I can use regex. I would certainly parse it and remove if I could

Comment: @LeonardoLana perhaps do preprocessing before passing it to dust?

Comment: Absolutely preprocess it.  Even if you manage to somehow get this regex to work, in a month you'll have no idea how the regex works, and minor tweaks will take far too much of your time.  Write clear code.

Comment: It might be an option to use jq.

Comment: Sometimes you just cannot use the way you wanted to altough you still need to solve the problem. The value cannot be removed using javascript, that's it. So there's no way to solve it, thank you

Comment: perfect case is parsing through logs and removing instances of `"password"` from json. you might now want the memory overhead of parsing everything to an object.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you have any way of using a parser it's a more stable and readable solution. The regex `\s*\"attr\" *: *\".*\"(,|(?=\s*\}))` should be shorter and better.

[Example](https://regex101.com/r/PAlqYi/2)

Several changes I made to help:

1. Don't use so many character classes like `[,]`. If there is only one element in a character class it should be left by itself.
2. Only use numbered counts when required. Ex: `{0,1}` is `?` and `{1}` is pointless.
3. Instead of searching for a comma in the previous line to see if it is the end of a list checking if there is a `}` following the line allows you to group the conditionals together.
4. A positive lookahead is used at the end to search for `}` so it wouldn't be removed during the substitution.

---

**Update with bugfix** mentioned in comments. Trailing commas would be left if the attribute is last. The simplest way I found to fix this was to match both cases. So, you'll have to fill in attr twice.

`(,\s*\"attr\" *: *\".*\"|(?=\s*\}))|(\s*\"attr\" *: *\".*\"(,|(?=\s*\})))`

[Examples with added tests cases](https://regex101.com/r/syaVbq/3)

Comment: one problem is that if the `attr` is the last property in the string, it will leave a trailing comma from the property preceding it.

Comment: Thanks @FlavorScape! I fixed this with a more convoluted regex. This is a really good example of why regex really isn't a good tool for this.

Comment: It is good for cleaning stuff like PII from server logs since there’s less performance overhead than parsing, cleaning, then stringifying again.

Comment: Hi @AlexCollins. I observed your solution, and even in your last update, it only supports string values, but not numbers, bools, nulls, arrays, or objects. How would you handle that?

Comment: Minor changes to the select portion should work. Like this one for digits. `(,\s*\"attr\" *: *\d+|(?=\s*\}))|(\s*\"attr\" *: *\d+(,|(?=\s*\})))`. But, I'll see if there is a clean generic solution later.

Answer (score 3):

I modified the regex from the first example, it works better even if is Flat JSON

`\s*\"attr\" *: *(\"(.*?)\"(,|\s|)|\s*\{(.*?)\}(,|\s|))`

[Example](https://regex101.com/r/dXYgzk/1)

Comment: one problem is that if the `attr` is the last property in the string, it will leave a trailing comma from the property preceding it.