# Regular Expression to strip sensitive information from a JSON object

Tags: regex

I have a JSON object something like below from which i wanted to strip out sensitive information like password, mobile no, etc. using Regular Expressions,

Example JSON

```
{
   "username":"abc",
   "password":"xyz123",
   "Security":{
      "SecurityQuestion":"what is your first pet name",
      "SecurityAnswer": "snoopy"
   }
}
```

From the above JSON object, I wanted to strip out sensitive information like "password" and "SecurityAnswer". I tried various regular expression patterns but it was removing only either any one of the item.

I need help or guidance on how to construct a regular expression, in which i can include any names in the expression and then those fields will be stripped out of the JSON.

Expected Output:

```
{
   "username":"abc",
   "Security":{
      "SecurityQuestion":"what is your first pet name"
   }
}
```

Note: If a password is the last property, then the expression should be able to remove the comma (,) also from the previous property.

I tried the expression from [Regex remove json property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46160681/regex-remove-json-property) with various combinations but none were working as per my requirement.

Comment: Don't use regexes for this.  Use an actual JSON library and edit the resulting object.

Comment: Do you really need to use regex? JSON is pretty good with javascript....

Comment: we are currently using CA API Management Suite and it expects a regular expression only to strip the data. I have no option but to use a regex only.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get values from JSON, you don't need to use regex and make a very complex regular expression.

```
var data = {
  "username":"abc",
  "password":"xyz123",
  "Security":{
  "SecurityQuestion":"what is your first pet name",
  "SecurityAnswer": "snoopy"
   }
}
```

That is your object, now if you want to retrieve the data simply treat it like a json.

```
function retrieveData( Obj ) {
    return {
      username: Obj.username,
      Security:{
         SecurityQuestion: Obj.Security.SecurityQuestion
       }
    }
}

var extractedData = retrieveData(data);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. However, we are currently using CA API Management Suite and it expects a regular expression only to strip the data. I have no option but to use a regex only. We will get an incoming JSON request and for logging purposes, we have to use a regex to strip out sensitive information and log them, so i dont have an option to write any code.

Comment: But, a regular expression is not the same in Javascript than PHP than Python and so on.. Each programming language has its own delimiters and expressions. I've never heard about that API but it should use some kind of programming language I guess.

Comment: Unfortunately, the API tool does not expose any programming language to customize the behavior. The tool is designed in such a way that, we can add assertions and customize it with the inbuilt properties only.

Comment: Then the API should provide a documentation to get around regex and data treatment.