# remove matching key object from localstorage using javascript

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I am having trouble with removing a user based on what is inputted in a text field. My localstorage has the data below. With users being the **key** and the **values** being the list of objects with username and genrePref.

```
// Saved in localstorage
users = {
    jon: {username: 'Jon', genrePref: 'rock'},
    lucy: {username: 'Lucy', genrePref: 'pop'},
    mike: {username: 'Mike', genrePref: 'rock'},
    luke: {username: 'Luke', genrePref: 'house'},
    james: {username: 'James', genrePref: 'house'},
    dave: {username: 'Dave', genrePref: 'bass'},
    sarah: {username: 'Sarah', genrePref: 'country'},
    natalie: {username: 'Natalie', genrePref: 'bass'}
}
```

I have written a function in Javascript which gets called when the form is submitted it passes the username as the parameter and calls the function.

```
function deleteUser(username) {
    const users = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("users"));
    const user = users[username];
    localStorage.removeItem("users", user);
}
```

This removes everything from the localStorage instead of the one username.
I searched online for an answer, and tried to convert the object to array but I couldn't get it to work. Any tips to go about this problem are appreciated !

Comment: Local storage stores **strings**. You don't seem to be parsing the string in any way (for instance, via `JSON.parse`). How are you storing the information you've shown as "Saved in localstorage"?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46160681/regex-remove-json-property#46161486

Comment: `removeItem("users")` will indeed remove `users` from the localStorage. No surprise here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per MDN documentation on removeItem function, the first parameter is the key of the object you want to remove.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/removeItem

With your implementation, you are basically removing entire `users` object.
Both `getItem` and `removeItem` operates on keys of `localstorage`, so for example, for

```
localStorage = {
 'fruits': {
  'apples': ['one', 'two', 'three'],
  'peaches': ['one', 'two', 'three'],
  'oranges': ['one', 'two', 'three']
 }
}
```

your `removeItem` would remove entirety of `apples` or `peaches`. You can't use it to remove something deeper in values.

What you would want to do is get entire `fruits`, remove the key and pass it to `setItem` again

```
const fruits= JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('fruits')) // remember that localStorage stores strings only
delete fruits['oranges'];
localStorage.setItem('fruits', fruits);
```

For the best solution you would want to deeply clone this object to avoid mutations

Answer (score 3):

`localStorage.removeItem()` does not take two params but one.
You are passing it `users`, which it takes as key and deletes corresponding matching item from storage.

```
function deleteUser(username) {
    const users = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("users"));
    delete users[username];
    localStorage.setItem("users", JSON.stringify(users));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you really have that stored in local storage, you've encoded it in some way (perhaps JSON?) when saving. You have to *decode* it when retrieving it.

For instance, if it were JSON, you'd do this:

```
function deleteUser(username) {
    // Get *and parse* the data
    const users = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("users"));
    // Remove the named user from the object
    delete users[username];
    // Store the updated object
    localStorage.setItem("users", JSON.stringify(users));
}
```

But if you're using something else (XML, whatever), just do whatever the deserialization step is where you see `JSON.parse` above, and do the serialization step where you see `JSON.stringify`.

Comment: *(Ooops, bit of an editing error there -- if you see `removeItem` above, hit refresh. It should be `setItem`.)*